# XGZP6859D Pressure Sensor with Stm32f302R8

Tags: c, embedded, sensors, stm32f3

I want to create an API to get value from `XGZP6859D` pressure sensor using the `stm32f302r8 nucleo` board,

Here's its datasheet http://cfsensor.com/static/upload/file/20210110/XGZP6859D%20Pressure%20Sensor%20Module.pdf.

I wrote all the register in the API, and I declared a function that will help to get the pressure value from the sensor.

Would anyone help me or give some tips how can write the function? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show what you have tried so far to solve the problem. Provide some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and tell where exactly you are stuck. You might also find [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) useful to read. If you already know how to access the sensor (write the registers) what is your specific problem with reading some other registers?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the documentation says:

> I2C Device Address:0X6D

> 1. Read the 0xA5 register value, put the read binary value "and" on "11111111101" then write to 0xA5.
> 2. Send instructions 0x0A to 0x30 register for one temperature acquisition, one pressure data acquisition.
> 3. Read the 0x30 register address. If Sco bit is 0,signify the acquisition end, the data can be read.
> 4. Read 0x06, 0x07, 0x08 register address data to form a 24-bit AD value (pressure data AD value)

Assuming you have some basic i2c read/write functionality and the i2c address of 0X6D, a pressure read sudo-function would look something like this:

```
// 1
i2cSensorAddress = 0x6D; // Make sure you address the sensor properly
int8_t reg = i2cSensorRead(0xA5);
i2cSensorWrite(0xA5, reg & 0xFD); //11111101 in hex

// 2
i2cSensorWrite(0x30, 0x0A);

// 3
while (!(i2cSensorRead(0x30) & 0x08)) { // Wait for transaction (SCO is bit 3)
    sleep();
}

// 4
int32_t pressureData = 0;
int8_t dataAddr = 0x06;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    pressureData = pressureData << 8;
    pressureData |= i2cSensorRead(dataAddr++);
}

return pressureData;
```

Hope that points you in the right direction! Good luck